# Can I use Auto Cad on Mac Book pro (early2008)

Tags: macbook-pro, autocad

I want to use Auto Cad but only have a Mac Book Pro (early 2008).
Can I buy a Mac mini and connect it to the Mac Book Pro as a screen?
Would that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only Macs that can be used as screens are non-retina iMacs from 2009 or later.